# Issue with rolling update

Tags: kubernetes

I am running Kubernetes v1.4.6+coreos.0 and a couple of days ago my CoreOS machine auto updated. Since the reboot I am no longer able to run a rolling-update. 
When I try I get the following output:

```
Created rhubarb-ui-rc-e41f9fd2ded4a5f1ccb31121342cbc59
Scaling up rhubarb-ui-rc-e41f9fd2ded4a5f1ccb31121342cbc59 from 0 to 1, scaling down rhubarb-ui-rc from 1 to 0 (keep 1 pods available, don't exceed 2 pods)
Scaling rhubarb-ui-rc-e41f9fd2ded4a5f1ccb31121342cbc59 up to 1
Scaling rhubarb-ui-rc down to 0
Update succeeded. Deleting old controller: rhubarb-ui-rc
Renaming rhubarb-ui-rc to rhubarb-ui-rc-e41f9fd2ded4a5f1ccb31121342cbc59
error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

and I end up with the following replication controllers:

```
rhubarb-ui-rc                                       0         0         0         4m
rhubarb-ui-rc-e41f9fd2ded4a5f1ccb31121342cbc59      1         1         1         4m
```

Struggling to debug why this is. Any idead?

Comment: Anything interesting in `kubelet` logs?

Comment: No I don't see anything interesting in any logs. In the end I had to rebuild the cluster to get it working. All running the same version so my suspicion is it had to be something to do with the reboot. I still have the broken cluster though as I need to understand what this was before I put this into production.